# Service shortcut to open terminal at the folder doesn't work on mac os Big Sur

Tags: terminal, finder, big-sur

I want to open a terminal at the current folder which is selected in the finder using a keyboard shortcut, but it is not working on Mac OS Big Sur.
I added the following shortcut in the **System Preferences** ▶ **Keyboard** ▶ **Shortcut** ▶ **Services**

[image: Added shortcut image]

At the top, as you can see, I have added a shortcut for "New Terminal at Folder" (<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) but when I try this shortcut it doesn't work, it just moves act as like I am pressing <kbd>T</kbd> and navigates to a file which has <kbd>T</kbd> in the name.

I tried another shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open iTerm2, and it is working fine.

I wonder why the terminal shortcut is not working for me.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: no @NecipSunmaz, I am now using iTerm2 terminal only.